# Limit with infinity (Who is correct?)

Tags: limits

$$\lim_{x\to\ -\infty} \frac{\sqrt{3x^2}}{x}$$

A friend claimed that this is equal to  $-\infty$

I did:
$$\require{cancel}
\lim_{x\to\ -\infty} \frac{\sqrt{3}|x|}{x} = -\frac{\sqrt{3}\cancel\infty}{\cancel\infty} = -\sqrt{3}$$

Who is right?

Comment: $\frac{\infty}{\infty}$ has no sense

Comment: Did you forget a negative in your work?  (In the middle fraction, perhaps you meant (even though it's bad notation) for the denominator to be $-\infty$).

Comment: But you're correct.

Comment: You should never ever write $\frac{\infty}{\infty}$.  Instead, note that since $x$ is approaching $-\infty$, the value of $|x|$ is $-x$.  Then, cancel your $x$'s.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your answer is correct but the method is not right:

$$
\lim_{x\rightarrow -\infty} \frac{\sqrt{3x^2}}{x}\\
\lim_{x\rightarrow -\infty} \frac{\sqrt{3}|x|}{x}\\
$$

since $x<0$ then $|x| = -x$ so you get:

$$
\lim_{x\rightarrow -\infty} -\frac{\sqrt{3}x}{x}\quad (not\quad \frac{\infty}{\infty})\\
\lim_{x\rightarrow -\infty} -\sqrt{3} = -\sqrt{3}\\
$$

Answer (score 2):

For $x<0$,
$$\frac{\sqrt{3x^2}}x=-\sqrt 3$$
Thus, the limit is $-\sqrt 3$.

Your result is correct, but you should avoid including $\infty$ in algebraic expressions. $\infty$ is not a number and operations with it are not defined.

Answer (score 1):

We can write  $$\displaystyle \lim_{x\rightarrow -\infty}\frac{\sqrt{3x^2}}{x} = \lim_{x\rightarrow -\infty}{\sqrt{3}}\cdot \frac{|x|}{x} = -\sqrt{3}$$

above we have Used  $$\displaystyle \bullet\; \sqrt{x^2} = |x|$$ and $$\bullet \; \displaystyle |x| = -x\;,x\leq 0$$

Answer (score 1):

For $x<0$ the function is constantly $-\sqrt{3}$.

So by obviousness you are correct, but aspects of your work are not proper.